# i just want to connect mysql database from other server

Tags: php, mysql

example : mydatabase is on google.com/phpmyadmin
and i want to insert data from yahoo.com/insertdata.php

both domains are not on same server both domains are on different servers 
so how to connect database

```
<?php
    $server   = "38.89.136.77";
    $database = "dbname";
    $username = "dbusers";
    $password = "password";

    $mysqlConnection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if (!$mysqlConnection)
    {
        echo "Please try later.";
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);

        echo " database is connected";
    }
?>
```

this code is not working how can i do it get error Please try later.

Comment: First, get the *actual* error. Look in your error logs or add error checking to your PHP script.

Comment: IP address maybe? Also, what is the point of providing that generic code? what have you actually tried? You can edit your original question by clicking on the **_edit_** link

Comment: have you tried catching errors? try this [mysqli_connect_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Then you get all errors displayed.

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }
?>
```

Then post your error here in the comments, so I can help you.

Comment: got this message when i try this

Failed to connect to MySQL: (1130) Host 'lardoon.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
 because i am replace localhost with my server ip address